# JPA Cascade ALL to skip unmodified entities

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

When we update a root entity with CASCADE.ALL option all the child objects also gets updated in JPA.
If I know before hand that a pariticular child entity is not modifed , is there a provision to denote in the entity that it is not modified  , so that unnecessary update query is not fired.

We can very well exclude the particular child from the parent collection , so that JPA will not update anything . 
I would like to know if there is any flag to denote at Entity level to specifiy that no properties are modified

Comment: With Hibernate at least, no update query will be executed if the state of the entity hasn't changed since the entity has been loaded. And anyway, this looks like premature optimization.

Comment: Cascade all will only cascade the merge/persist operation to the referenced entities.  If this is a merge, it should only merge changes anyway.  If you want to control the merge, then do not use the cascade all option, and instead merge parent and children separately.